# Rails dynamically apply skip navigation on ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through and updating a website with skip navigation. I'm trying to do a dynamic anchor tag with id's that are dynamic but hitting a wall.

```
<% Location.all.each do |location|%>
 <a href=<%="#{location.title}"%> class="skip">Skip to locations</a>
<% end %>

<%= content_tag :div, :class => "location", :data => {:id => location.id, :title => location.title, :latitude => location.latitude, :longitude => location.longitude} do %>
  <%= content_tag :div, location.title, :class => "location-title" , :id => "#{location.title}"%>
```

The id is showing correctly on the div but the anchor tag isn't being set as an ID. I've tried doing: <%='#"#{location.title}"' but this ends up with: a link of quote#{location.title}quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ActionView` helper:

```
<%= link_to "Skip to locations", location.title, class: 'skip' %>
```

Comment: I'm using a variation of this and putting a div around it with the class as it's actually not applying the class to the anchor tag for some reason.

Comment: Try this `<%= link_to "Skip to locations", location.title, { class: 'skip' } %>` refering to this signature `link_to(body, url, html_options = {})`, for more information visit this [link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')' ...nk_to

Comment: Can you please show me that part of the code, so I can check?

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a href="#<%={location.title}%>" class="skip">Skip to locations</a>` to avoid having the `#` sign escaped by ERB